# MVC DropDown on LayoutPage to affect all pages

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'd like to have 3 dropdowns on the Layout shared view (With viewbags from a model that I'll create) that will affect the data displayed on all the other views.

What's the best way of doing this?
[image: 1]
Dropdown 1 is just needed to filter dropdown 2. Dropdown 2 will affect all pages. DropDown 3 will just affect the "ScoreCard" one.

EDIT 1

I now have the basemodel model and controller for it as follows.

```
namespace RapidScan_v2.Models
{
    public class LayoutBaseModel
  {
    [Key]
    public string ContractID { get; set; }
    public string ContractName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SnapshotMonth { get; set; }  
  }
}
```

Controler:

```
namespace RapidScan_v2.Controllers
{
public class LayoutBaseModelController : Controller
{
    private RapidScanEntities2 db = new RapidScanEntities2();

    // GET: LayoutBaseModel
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<LayoutBaseModel> model = new List<LayoutBaseModel>();

        var fact_contract_actions_mn = (from a in db.v_contract_detail
                                        join b in db.fact_contract_actions_mn
                                             on a.ContractID equals b.ContractID
                                        select new  
                                        {
                                            ContractID = b.ContractID,
                                            ContractName = a.ContractName,
                                            CountryCode = a.CountryCode,
                                            CountryName = a.CountryName,
                                            SnapshotMonth = a.SnapshotMonth
                                        }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in fact_contract_actions_mn)
        {
            model.Add(new LayoutBaseModel()
            {
                ContractID = item.ContractID,
                ContractName = item.ContractName,
                CountryCode = item.CountryCode,
                CountryName = item.CountryName,
                SnapshotMonth = item.SnapshotMonth
            });
        }

        ViewBag.CountryName = new SelectList(db.v_contract_detail, "CountryCode", "CountryName");
        ViewBag.ContractID = new SelectList(db.v_contract_detail, "ContractID","ContractName");
        ViewBag.SNapshotMonth = new SelectList(db.v_contract_detail, "SnapshotMonth");


        return View(model);
      }
  }
}
```

Added to the "_Layout" View.
    { @model IEnumerable < RapidScan_v2.Models.LayoutBaseModel> }

But now an error pops up:
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type       'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RapidScan_v2.Models.ActionsBenefitViews]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RapidScan_v2.Models.LayoutBaseModel]'."

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I'm creating the model to the dropdowns at the moment. Just wanted any pointers of what to do next. This is my first project in MVC.

Comment: IMHO to implement dropdowns into layout page you need a single viewmodel that shared across all pages, and place every single page model into it (since view only accepts one model to be passed at a time). Cascading dropdown between 1 & 2 can be created using AJAX call, but I can't figure out how third dropdown will affect certain model.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I just updated the question with the model and controller. What do you think?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I'm building up based on your reply. Any tips to solve this issue now? Thanks